# Split string into first word and remaining text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a string `"@user hello world"` I wish I split into `"@user"` and `"hello world"`. The contents of each substring is irrelevant, I just want to separate the original string into the first word and the remainder. It could also be `"a b c d e f"` into `"a"` and `"b c d e f"`. How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) takes an optional second parameter for the max number of splits. Here you just want to split off the first item so you can use:

```
s = "@user hello world"
a, b = s.split(' ', 1)
a, b
# ('@user', 'hello world')
```

Answer (score 2):

The split method with a parameter will do the job.

```
test_str = "This is a sentence"
print(test_str.split(' ', 1 ))
```